# How to add values from a queue to systemverilog functional coverage ignore_bins/illegal_bins?

Tags: system-verilog

I am writing a configurable SystemVerilog functional coverage coverpoint. I have an enum `response_t` as follows:

```
typedef enum bit [1:0] {OK, ERR1, ERR2, ERR3} response_t;
```

I want to add all the entries of enum to individual coverpoint bins as follows:

```
response_t r;

r_cp : coverpoint r {
  bins ok = {OK};
  bins err_1 = {ERR1};
  bins err_2 = {ERR2};
  bins err_3 = {ERR3};
}
```

The coverpoint above is generic. Now I want to make it configurable for users so that users can optionally add few of these bins to ignore/illegal by adding the values to a queue as follows:

```
class cfg;
  ...
  response_t ignore_bins_q[$];
  response_t illegal_bins_q[$];
endclass
```

Now I tried to modify my coverpoint as follows:

```
r_cp : coverpoint r {
  bins ok = {OK};
  bins err_1 = {ERR1};
  bins err_2 = {ERR2};
  bins err_3 = {ERR3};
  ignore_bins ignore = {cfg.ignore_bins_q};
  illegal_bins illegal = {cfg.illegal_bins_q};
}
```

The tool I am using is vcs, and I get the following error when I tried it this way:

> Expression of type 'array' used in left value range is not legal.

How can I work around this problem?

Comment: ignore_bins ignore = {cfg.ignore_bins_q};

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the {}'s

```
ignore_bins ignore = cfg.ignore_bins_q;
illegal_bins illegal = cfg.illegal_bins_q;
```

Remember that the queues need to be populated by the time the covergroup gets constructed.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but I am getting the following error if I do so

Error-[NYI] Not Yet Implemented
Feature is not yet supported: expression other than coverpoint label as
coverpoint bin value.

Comment: *Not Yet Implemented* means what it says. The tool recognizes the feature but has not implemented it yet. Try another tool.